# Extracting a page results in NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, itext, nullreferenceexception

I'm trying to test extraction of a single page from a PDF document, but I'm getting  a `NullReferenceException` whenever I try.

```
var document = new Document();
var stream = new MemoryStream();
var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, stream);

document.Open();
document.Add(new Paragraph("This is page 1."));
document.NewPage();
document.Add(new Paragraph("This is page 2."));
document.Close();

var copystream = new MemoryStream();
var copy = new PdfCopy(document, copystream);
copy.Open();
var reader = new PdfReader(stream.ToArray());
var page = copy.GetImportedPage(reader, 2);
copy.AddPage(page);
copy.Close(); // code throws exception here
```

I've tried adding `writer.CloseStream = false`, but I still end up with the same `NullReferenceException`:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at iTextSharp.text.Document.get_Left()
   at iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfDocument.SetNewPageSizeAndMargins()
   at iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfDocument.NewPage()
   at iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfDocument.Close()
   at iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfCopy.Close()
   at iTextTest.Controllers.HomeController.Index() in line 41
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Well that seems to be a bug in iTextSharp. They may want to add null handling there and throw the proper exception, like "No margin set" or whatever the root cause is. [Browse the source: the `Left` property does `return pageSize.GetLeft(marginLeft);`](http://sourceforge.net/p/itextsharp/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/src/core/iTextSharp/text/Document.cs), where `pageSize` presumably is `null`.

Comment: Are you sure that you've used the PDF library you're using correctly?  According to your code you are creating a PdfCopy from a closed document.  Try opening the document for reading after closing it (keeping it open might leave the position in the wrong place) and using that for the copy.

Comment: @SteveLillis The issue with not calling `document.Close` is that `PdfReader` won't work correctly because, and I'm assuming here, `document.Close()` adds the xref table.

Comment: @CodeCaster So, should I set the page margins myself or something?

Comment: Well it seems to be doing that in the parameterless `Document()` constructor, so I wouldn't know... Maybe you can download and compile the source to debug from there, or read it until you see where it goes wrong. Make sure you're looking at the right version of the code.

Comment: You use the `Document document` initially to generate the first document, close it, and then use it again for the second one. @SteveLillis already mentioned this. Yes, the close is necessary to finish the first document. But you need a not-closed instance to create the second document. Thus, add a `document = new Document();` before `var copystream = new MemoryStream();`

Comment: I agree with @mkl. The `Document` object is **only** for working with new documents. It is an abstraction that allows you to more easily add things to a PDF but once you close it, the abstractions are converted into the more obscure PDF syntax. On your second pass, your `PdfCopy` is in fact creating a brand new document, the fact that you are importing pages is incidental.

Comment: @mkl @ChrisHaas I see. I think I interpreted the documentation incorrectly. I had assumed that the `Document` used in the `PdfCopy` constructor was the copy source rather than an abstraction for working with new documents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please change your code like this:

```
var document = new Document();
var stream = new MemoryStream();
var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, stream);

document.Open();
document.Add(new Paragraph("This is page 1."));
document.NewPage();
document.Add(new Paragraph("This is page 2."));
document.Close();

document = new Document(); // this is the line you need to add
var copystream = new MemoryStream();
var copy = new PdfCopy(document, copystream);
copy.Open();
var reader = new PdfReader(stream.ToArray());
var page = copy.GetImportedPage(reader, 2);
copy.AddPage(page);
copy.Close(); // code throws exception here
```

You are reusing the `document` object you used to create a new document from scratch. That `document` instance is already closed. When you use the `document` in the context of `PdfCopy`, you need a new `Document` instance.

Answer (score 0):

I have reviewed the source for PdfDocument as can be found here: http://sourceforge.net/p/itextsharp/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/src/core/iTextSharp/text/pdf/PdfDocument.cs#l2334

PdfDocument assigns the value of private field `nextPageSize` to field `pageSize` at the start of the method `SetNewPageSizeAndMargins`.  To stop `nextPageSize` being `null` (and therefore causing your `pageSize` to be set to null and triggering a `NullReferenceException` when it is next accessed) call `SetPageSize` on the document before closing the copy.

To keep the default page size, call `SetPageSize` as follows:

```
document.SetPageSize(document.PageSize);
```

This is most likely an oversight by the developers of the PdfDocument class, which I suspect is meant to be setting a default value for nextPageSize and isn't.

Comment: I put in `copy.SetPageSize(document.PageSize)` after `copy.AddPage(page)` but I'm still getting the same exception on `copy.Close()`.

Comment: My mistake. Please put it on the document.  It's when the copy closes the document that the document throws the exception.  Updated my answer.

Comment: I added `document.SetPageSize(document.PageSize)` before `document.Close()` but I'm still getting an exception thrown. I stepped through the source code, and it seems the issue is indeed with `nextPageSize` as it's still `null`.

Comment: *This is most likely an oversight by the developers of the PdfDocument class, which I suspect is meant to be setting a default value for nextPageSize and isn't.* - `document.PageSize` is initialized in non-closed instances, so no oversight here. Probably critical code could check whether or not the document is closed, though.

Comment: But closing a PDFDocument without calling SetPageSize causes the default pageSize to be overwritten with null.  That seems like an unexpected behaviour to me, especially as not all implementations of a document will do the same?

Comment: A closed document is closed and, therefore, shall not be used anymore.

Comment: Ah, I see.  Thank you for clarifying.  Perhaps an InvalidOperationException or similar would be useful for developers trying to use a closed document, similar to when a developer attempts to use an already disposed object?  It would help prevent confusion such as this.